# Norm notation clarification

Tags: notation, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I have two questions about $L^p$-type norm notation.

Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and $p \geq 1$ is fixed.

(1) Consider the notation $\|f\|_{L^p([0,1];H)}$ in comparison to  $\|f\|_{L^p([0,1])}$.

Question 1: Is the former to indicate that for $x\in[0,1]$ fixed, $f(x) \in H$ and $\int_0^1 |f(y)|^p dy<\infty$, and the latter to indicate the same with $H=\mathbb{R}$?

(2) Suppose $v=v(t,x)$ is a function in $L^{\infty}([0,T];  L^p([0,1];H))$.

Question 2: Does this notation mean that $\sup_{t\in[0,T]} |v(t,x)| <\infty$ and that for $t$ fixed $v(t,\cdot) \in L^p([0,1];H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v=v(t,x)$ is a function in $L^{\infty}([0,T];  L^p([0,1];H))$.

Mean $$\sup_{t\in[0,T]} \left(\int_0^1|v(t,x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p} <\infty$$

and $$\|f\|_{L^p([0,1];H)} =\left(\int_0^1\|f(x)\|_H^pdx\right)^{1/p} $$
that is $$x\mapsto\|f(x)\|_H $$
is in $L^p([0,1])$